# Linuxで10秒後にシャットダウン

Tags: linux, shell

Debian 10 で、10秒後にシャットダウンすることは可能でしょうか？

shutdown -P +1  で、１分後にシャットダウンできると思いますが、長すぎるので、
秒単位で指定したいのですが

＜追記＞
組み込み系のＣ＋＋アプリで、電源をいきなり切られたくないので、アプリの中からシャットダウン
したいのですが、shutdown now　だと、デストラクタがちゃんと実行されるのか不明だったので、
適当な猶予時間が欲しかったためです。

Comment: まぁ、`sleep 10; shutdown now` とか。

Comment: この辺のページ [システムをシャットダウン](https://www.k-tanaka.net/unix/shutdown.php), [分類： UNIXコマンド辞典>>shutdown](https://codezine.jp/unixdic/w/shutdown) だと秒で指定できるオプションがあるようですが。ここ [shutdown in 30 seconds?](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/shutdown-in-30-seconds-806526/) だとそれは正確ではなさそうです。試しにやってみるとか。

Comment: Debian 10 では systemd が採用されていて、ソースコード上で確認すると1分単位でしか指定できません。`systemd/src/systemctl/sysv-compat.c:parse_shutdown_time_spec()` function

Comment: なぜ10秒待つ必要があるのかがはっきりすると、適した方法があるかもしれません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sleep` コマンドと組み合わせてみてはどうでしょうか？

例: 10秒後にshutdown

```
# sleep 10; shutdown -h
```

Answer (score -1):

"shutdown -h now"　が素直で最速。

３秒後とか、７秒後とかいうように秒単位でどうしても指定したい理由があるのですか？

１分では遅すぎるというのなら、最速でシャットダウンさせるというのがベストだと思います。